# Proving inverse of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given the identity matrix $I_n$ and a matrix $J_n$ with only 1's as every element.

I must prove that if $n>0$ then $(I_n - J_n)^{-1} = I_n - \frac{1}{n-1} J_n$

I'm trying to understand if there is some sort of theorem that states that $(I_n - J_n)^{-1} = I_n^{-1} - J_n^{-1}$ or something like that?

Comment: $J_n^{-1}$ doesn’t exist as $J_n$ is not invertible.

Comment: Then I need some hints :(

Comment: I've got: $(I - c \cdot J)(I-J) = I$

Where C is the constant $\frac{1}{n-1}$

How can I proceed?

Comment: Can someone explain the last step in the algebra proof http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441505/proving-the-inverse-of-a-matrix-equals-i-n-frac1n-1a

Comment: Why is $A^2 = nA$?

Answer (score 3):

Just multiply out the things that are supposed to be inverses of each other, and check that it gives $I_n$.

Comment: Would that be a proof?

Comment: If you prove that $AB = I$, then you have proven that $B=A^{-1}$. By definition.

Comment: ...and by uniqueness of the inverse.

Comment: Please see my new comment above.

Comment: I need an explanation of the steps in this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441505/proving-the-inverse-of-a-matrix-equals-i-n-frac1n-1a

The one with 7 votes. How does he just plug an $n$ in and how does he get rid of the $-A$?